# C# 2010 access app.config values of program in called dll

Tags: dll, c#-3.0, app-config

I have a C# 2010 console/desktop application that obtains its own database connections from its app.config file. This application adds a reference to a dll so that it can access another C# console/windows application.

The main C# 2010 console/desktop application needs to be able to access the database connections of the program that is called in the dll. The database connections of the called program are stored in an app.config file.

Thus can you show me code or explain to me how the main C# 2010 console/desktop application can obtain the database connections stored in the app.config file for the program that is accessed by the dll?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one config file, named after the executable and config extension. Just call:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx

Comment: The above does njot solve the problem. The "main" C# 2010 desktop application obtains its database connection string values from its app.config file. However the 'main' pforam uses its config file and not the config file for the DLL. Thus can you tell me how to make the main program access the database connections from the app.config file of the DLL?

Comment: dll's dosen't have a config file. Instead, merge all config values in a single config file and you're done. Name this file the same that your exe with .config extension.